# Pandas - Mapping dict with multiple index to column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have two large data sets which I can't do the aggregations by combining two dataframes. I have to do the aggregation on `df_train` first, then map the values to the `df_test`.

`df_train` and `df_test` have the same exact `id1` and `id2`, but the `df_test` have more samples. I'm computing the target mean on `id1` and `id2` and store it as a dictionary for memory issues.

```
target_mean = df_train.groupby(['id1', 'id2'])['target'].mean().to_dict()
```

This is the output of the aggregation. The keys are tuple pairs with `id1` as the first element and `id2` as the second element, and the values are target means of the groups.

```
{(0, 0): 146.45497131347656,
 (1, 0): 74.86539459228516,
 (2, 0): 14.551384925842285,
 (3, 0): 235.5499725341797,
 (4, 0): 976.5567626953125,
 (5, 0): 17.894445419311523,
 (6, 0): 64.06660461425781,
 (7, 0): 350.33416748046875,
 (7, 1): 3097.043701171875,
 (8, 0): 256.92779541015625,
 (9, 0): 72.7147445678711 }
```

How can I map those values to `id1` and `id2` columns properly?

(There are **60 million** rows of data, **1449** `id1` and **4** `id2` values, so speed is important)

**EDIT**:

```
df_train[['id1', 'id2']].map(target_mean)
```

I tried this, but `map` is only supported by `pd.Series`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think better is use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) here:

```
target_mean = df_train.groupby(['id1', 'id2'])['target'].mean().rename('avg')

df_test = df_test.join(target_mean, on=['id1', 'id2'])
```

Your solution is possible, but I guess slowier with `map` by `MultiIndex`:

```
target_mean = df_train.groupby(['id1', 'id2'])['target'].mean().to_dict()
df_test['avg'] = df_test.set_index(['id1', 'id2']).index.map(target_mean)
```

Comment: Thanks, `join` works like magic. What is difference between `merge` and `join` in this case? Should I add `how='left'` to `join`?

Comment: @gunesevitan - `how='left'` is not necessary, because default parameter in `join`. Difference between  `merge` and `join` is mainly `join` by default use index for merging, `merge` by default by columns names specified in `on` parameter